# How to transfer cursor to the procedure dynamically and to set rowtype variable dynamically?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written the procedure with dynamically set cursor and %rowtype variable:

```
create or replace procedure process(source_table IN varchar2, my_cursor IN   sys_refcursor)
is

c sys_refCURSOR;
rec my_cursor%rowtype;

begin
Dbms_Output.put_line('process starts');
open c for 'select * from '||source_table;

loop
  fetch c into rec;  
  exit when c%notfound;
end loop;

close c;

  Dbms_Output.put_line('process is over');
end process;
```

I am going to transfer cursor to the procedure with the function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ddp_get_allitems (source_table IN Varchar2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM '|| source_table;
  RETURN my_cursor;
END ddp_get_allitems;
```

While compiling the procedure "process" I have the error:
    PLS-00320 the declaration of the type of the expression is incomplete or  malformed.
The compiler has hilighted the row with "rec my_cursor%rowtype;" as the error source. The varibale "source_table" and "my_cursor" are based upon the same table (select * from my_table).

So Why the error has arisen and how to remove it?

Comment: You can't take do that.   ref cursor has no concrete definition.  It is not a table row.

Comment: What is your goal? You can get the columns with package DBMS_SQL but you cannot use %ROWTYPE for that.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit:
well, I have a variable qty of tables with variable qty of fields. And I have the current procedure that uses static table names and static (declared explicitly) row types. I must to change or rewrite it to use varialble parameters (tables and rowtype variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PL/SQL is statically typed the compiler needs to know the types of all the variables at compile time.

So there is no room for advanced metaprogramming. I'm afraid you can't do that.

There are, however, *generic* types found at `SYS.STANDARD` and a few internal functions accepting them.

```
  -- The following data types are generics, used specially within package
  -- STANDARD and some other Oracle packages.  They are protected against
  -- other use; sorry.  True generic types are not yet part of the language.

  type "<ADT_1>" as object (dummy char(1));
  type "<RECORD_1>" is record (dummy char(1));
  type "<TUPLE_1>" as object (dummy char(1));
  type "<VARRAY_1>" is varray (1) of char(1);
  type "<V2_TABLE_1>" is table of char(1) index by binary_integer;
  type "<TABLE_1>" is table of char(1);
  type "<COLLECTION_1>" is table of char(1);
  type "<REF_CURSOR_1>" is ref cursor;
```

Take `"<ADT_1>"` for example. There is XMLTYPE constructor or DBMS_AQ ENQUEUE and DEQUEUE functions. You can pass any kind of object there.

For now you cannot use this datatype in custom functions since they are "not yet part of the language", but maybe some day there will be some support for this.

Comment: @ that young man: thanks for your reply :-) The hope has to be dead for sure... :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Just a thought to modify soe params which can basically same output
>   you want to achieve. Basically here for Function i have replaced
>   RETURN type as TABLE TYPE which can be easilt called in Procedure abd
>   rest manipulations can be done.Let me know if this helps

```
--SQL Object creation
CREATE TYPE source_table_obj IS OBJECT 
(<TABLE_ATTRIBITES DECLARATION>);

--SQL TABLE type creation
CREATE TYPE source_table_tab IS TABLE OF source_table_obj;

--Function creation with nested table type as RETURN type
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ddp_get_allitems(
    source_table IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN source_table_tab
AS
  src_tab source_table_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO src_tab FROM source_table;
  RETURN src_tab;
END ddp_get_allitems;

-- Using Function's OUT param as an IN Param for Procedure an do all the requird processing
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process(
    source_table IN VARCHAR2,
    src_tab_in   IN source_table_tab)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN src_tab_in.FIRST..src_tab_in.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('job processing');
  END LOOP;
END process;
```

Comment: @ Avrajit Roy:
Thanks for your answer. It looks nice but I see one drawback:

--SQL Object creation
CREATE TYPE source_table_obj IS OBJECT 
(<TABLE_ATTRIBITES DECLARATION>);

(<TABLE_ATTRIBITES DECLARATION>) - requires to declare table explicitly. 
But in my case, I do not know the exact table structure of incoming tables. In each case I could have a variable number of columns or the same number but different types.